# IE name of download file and its extension are wrong when Web site run on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, localhost, file-extension

I create name file for download file:

```
string fileName = Resources.Resource.VacationLimits + year + ".xlsx";
```

When aplication run on localhost - I can normal download file.
After build as  Release and publish Web on server, 
when I download file I have wrong file name without the file extension .xlsx in IE. In other browser I can download file with correct name and the file extension .xlsx.

all method:

```
 MemoryStream stream;
 var result = vacationService.GetVacationFile(out stream);
 string fileName = Resources.Resource.VacationLimits + year + ".xlsx";
 const string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
 return File(stream, contentType, fileName);
```

Comment: When you build as a release, and run it locally, does the same problem happen? I'm guessing there's something weird going on with IE's security zones between localhost and something outside of localhost.

Comment: @StevenV When I build as a release, and run it locally - it works correctly.

Comment: I'm guessing it's something with IE's security zones. Try resetting IE completely, or maybe on a different workstation?